# HTML change in A drupal site

Tags: theming

it has been suggested to me to delete this code piece from my site's files:

```
<link rel="shortlink" href="http://www.panchers.co.il/node/1" />
```

The problem is I haven't found the file which stores it... my theme is Pixture-Reloaded. thanks for your help.

Comment: It's probably module-generated, and thus never stored in files (except for cache, possibly). But we can't tell you which one, without knowing what you have enabled.

Answer (score 2):

The default [shortlink](https://code.google.com/p/shortlink/wiki/Specification) for the page is added by [`node_page_view()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_page_view/7), but if you have [Metatag](https://drupal.org/project/metatag) enabled, it will override the default behavior.

I usually tackle things like this in a [`hook_html_head_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_html_head_alter/7), eg

```
function MYTHEME_html_head_alter(&$head_elements) {
  // get rid of shortlink from metatag module
  unset($head_elements['metatag_shortlink']);

  // find the default shortlink from core, and zap it
  foreach ($head_elements as $key => $elements) {
    if (strpos($key, 'drupal_add_html_head_link:shortlink') === 0) {
      unset($head_elements[$key]);
    }
  }
}
```

The tricky part is that the element name from core doesn't have a consistent name, so you need to loop through find the right one to remove.  If that doesn't remove it, then you need to `dpm($head_elements)` and figure out the proper element to remove.